# Get a unique current user, depending on what Online Platform they are using

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Our goal is to measure if they are still active over the last month, and if not the last month the last time the user was active. We are storing two tables, Employees and Online Transactions. The Online transactions table is built from monthly reports where we go out to the Online Platforms and get a listing of all users, with the date their id was activated and when it was last logged in. We get other data that matters to us, like what role they have in the Online Platform and how much data they are storing.

The Employee table has termination dates for employees that have left the company, as well as a unique id. The unique id is what we join to the Online table.

We use these two tables to manage the Online tool access as well as to report overall usage of the platforms by individual user per platform. There are three different platforms used, Portal, AGOL or Training. The Online transactions table stores all three in the same table.

The issue is I am not understanding the proper way to get the results I’m looking for. I am attaching example code, which I know by the result set isn’t what I want. Of course, since this is PII, I must scrub my example results to remove information but still show what I am having trouble with.

```
SELECT DISTINCT   
    U.EMPLOYEE_TRACKING_ID,U.LAST_NAME, U.FIRST_NAME, U.EMAIL_ADDRESS, U.PERSON_TYPE, 
    U.SERVICE_LINE, U.SUPERVISOR_NAME, U.OFFICE_LOCATION, U.OFFICE_CITY, U.OFFICE_STATE, 
    U.OFFICE_COUNTRY, U.OFFICE_POSTAL_CODE, U.ACTUAL_TERMINATION_DATETIME, O.FiscalPeriod, 
    O.Role, O.Source, O.LogDate
FROM  dbo.Users U
INNER JOIN dbo.Online_Transactions O ON U.EMPLOYEE_TRACKING_ID = O.TrackingId
WHERE O.Source ='AGOL
```

In the example result set you can see that there are repeating records, because I have more than just the Tracking ID as part of the distinct, thus resulting in each field’s distinct value being considered.

Do I need to do some type of inner select to get down to the distinct user, by office and the latest log date they were reported? For example, our records go back 3.5 years, but what I want is the all unique users by the last time they logged in. I can remove the termination date for current users and keep the termination date so I can remove users who have left. I thought I would do a series of views to get me each scenario, therefore there would be a total of 6, one for each Online type and the second for terminated or not?

If anyone can help me learn how to do this.

```
EMPLOYEE_TRACKING_ID,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,EMAIL_ADDRESS,PERSON_TYPE,SERVICE_LINE,SUPERVISOR_NAME,OFFICE_LOCATION,OFFICE_CITY,OFFICE_STATE,OFFICE_COUNTRY,OFFICE_POSTAL_CODE,ACTUAL_TERMINATION_DATETIME,FiscalPeriod,Role,Source,LogDate
111483,Name4,User4,User4.Name4@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Melbourne,VIC,Australia,3008,4/30/2021,FY2020-Q4-08,AECOM PUBLISHER,AGOL,2020-09-02 00:00:00.000
111483,Name4,User4,User4.Name4@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Melbourne,VIC,Australia,3008,4/30/2021,FY2020-Q4-09,AECOM PUBLISHER,AGOL,2020-09-30 00:00:00.000
111483,Name4,User4,User4.Name4@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Melbourne,VIC,Australia,3008,4/30/2021,FY2021-Q1-11,AECOM PUBLISHER,AGOL,2021-02-02 00:00:00.000
111483,Name4,User4,User4.Name4@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Melbourne,VIC,Australia,3008,4/30/2021,FY2021-Q1-12,AECOM PUBLISHER,AGOL,2021-03-01 00:00:00.000
111483,Name4,User4,User4.Name4@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Melbourne,VIC,Australia,3008,4/30/2021,FY2021-Q2-01,AECOM PUBLISHER,AGOL,2021-05-01 00:00:00.000
111483,Name4,User4,User4.Name4@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Melbourne,VIC,Australia,3008,4/30/2021,FY2021-Q2-02,AECOM PUBLISHER,AGOL,2020-09-02 00:00:00.000
111483,Name4,User4,User4.Name4@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Melbourne,VIC,Australia,3008,4/30/2021,FY2021-Q2-03,AECOM PUBLISHER,AGOL,2021-01-04 00:00:00.000
113311,Name3,User3,User3.Name3@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Sydney,NSW,Australia,2000,5/21/2021,FY2020-Q3-06,AECOM COLLECTOR,AGOL,2020-09-02 00:00:00.000
14001627,Name1,User1,user1.name1@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Melbourne,VIC,Australia,3008,3/3/2021,FY2021-Q1-12,AECOM COLLECTOR,AGOL,2021-02-02 00:00:00.000
14001627,Name1,User1,user1.name1@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Melbourne,VIC,Australia,3008,3/3/2021,FY2021-Q2-01,AECOM COLLECTOR,AGOL,2021-04-01 00:00:00.000
14001627,Name1,User1,user1.name1@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Melbourne,VIC,Australia,3008,3/3/2021,FY2021-Q2-02,AECOM COLLECTOR,AGOL,2020-09-02 00:00:00.000
14007604,Name2,User2,User2.Name2@mycompany.com,Employee,NULL,,,Newcastle upon Tyne,POST-TWR,United Kingdom,NE1 2HF,9/30/2020,FY2020-Q2-03,AECOM COLLECTOR,AGOL,2020-09-02 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: You will both encourage others and make your issue more clear by removing the clutter from you code and sample data (and desired results - which is missing). The people names (and address etc.) are, at this point, irrelevant. All that is important is "unique id" - which apparently is the column "EMPLOYEE_TRACKING_ID". Do you see how that adds confusion? The same thought applies to the transaction information. Just include a bare minimum to illustrate the issue.

Comment: It would help greatly if you edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results

Comment: And your comments suggest a confusion about your goal. "distinct user, by office" seems to contradict the general idea of your first paragraph - measuring if a user is active. What do you desire as "output"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your Online_Transactions table has multiple entries for your users?

You could use a CROSS APPLY to get the one row note the ORDER BY to get the latest one

```
SELECT DISTINCT
U.EMPLOYEE_TRACKING_ID,U.LAST_NAME, U.FIRST_NAME, U.EMAIL_ADDRESS, U.PERSON_TYPE, 
U.SERVICE_LINE, U.SUPERVISOR_NAME, U.OFFICE_LOCATION, U.OFFICE_CITY, U.OFFICE_STATE, 
U.OFFICE_COUNTRY, U.OFFICE_POSTAL_CODE, U.ACTUAL_TERMINATION_DATETIME,
T.FiscalPeriod, T.Role, T.Source, T.LogDate
FROM dbo.Users AS U
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 O.FiscalPeriod, O.Role, O.Source, O.LogDate
    FROM dbo.Online_Transactions AS O
    WHERE O.TrackingId = U.EMPLOYEE_TRACKING_ID
    AND O.Source = 'AGOL'
    ORDER BY O.LogDate DESC
) AS T
```

This could also be done with an inner select sub query, but I like this syntax.
You might want to change CROSS APPLY for OUTER APPLY just to see the results, but I normally use CROSS APPLY which is like an INNER JOIN, in that it will only show users that have a match to an Online_Transaction.

Comment: OK I understand I over worded my question, and caused some confusion, but Andrew has given me code that I understand and is giving me the desired results.